# ERROR CDVLaunchScreen.storyboard IONIC V1 ON MAC

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

I am having the following error

[image]

when running:

```
ionic cordova build ios
```

Could anyone tell me how can I solve it? On android I had no compilation problems

Answer (score 0):

The error is

```
Named Colors are not supported prior to iOS 11
```

1. Locate your-app-name.xcodeproj
2. Open this file in Xcode
3. Click on the folder icon on top of the file drawer side panel in Xcode
4. Scroll down and you will notice Resources in red color text
5. Open CDVLaunchScreen.storyboard
6. Choose a Background color and Tint from right pane and File -> save
7. Press the Play button to build from Xcode

Other option

In config.xml of your Cordova project:

```
<preference name="deployment-target" value="12.0" />
```